# Profile target mismatch: /archetype-catalog.xml when release staging repo in Sonatype

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, sonatype, maven-central

I am trying to release artifacts to Sonatype for the first time, but I am getting this error, any ideas?

```
Profile target mismatch: /archetype-catalog.xml
```

See image from their UI[image]

Sonatype support responded with the following:

"Can your build be configured to not produce/upload the archetype.xml file? The staging rule is working as designed to prevent files that live outside the groupId structure that you've been approved for from being released."

Can someone help as to how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate project from maven archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DgroupId=io.github.name \
-DartifactId=artifactId \
-Dversion=1.0 \
-DpackageName=io.github.name \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.0 \
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It turns out there was a bug Sonatype had yesterday. Here is a link for someone else experiencing that issue on [Sonatype's jira system](https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/OSSRH/issues/OSSRH-44818?filter=allissues).  Try it now, releasing an artifact is working for me today.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21682802)

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.  My answer is that the questioner should try again today, as I believe he ran into a bug that Sonatype introduced recently and fixed last evening.